VB .NET list of 2D array of structure
I need to store in a 1D array some 2D arrays of a structure, that is:
Public Structure CodeBlock
    Public R As Integer
    Public C As Integer
    Public text_tx As String
    Public text_bx As String
    Public selected As Boolean
End Structure

Public code(nrows, ncols) As CodeBlock

Public history(5) As List(Of code) '<-- the problem


In List(Of code), code is supposed to be a type name; however, it is a variable. Since you don't have a type name for the 2d array, combine the two declarations into one.
Public history As List(Of CodeBlock(,)) ' List of 2D array of CodeBlock

Note that this is an empty list. You will have to add the elements like this:
history.Add(New CodeBlock(nRows - 1, nCols - 1) {})
history(0)(0) = ...
history(0)(1) = ...

Or assign the 2D array to a variable first
Dim code = New CodeBlock(nRows - 1, nCols - 1) {}
history.Add(code)
code(0) = ...
code(1) = ...


It tells you that "Type code is not defined", so all you need to do is make a class for Code.
Maybe you mean something like this:
Public history As List(Of Code)

Public Structure CodeBlock
    Public R As Integer
    Public C As Integer
    Public text_tx As String
    Public text_bx As String
    Public selected As Boolean
End Structure

Public Class Code

    Public Property Stuff As CodeBlock(,)

    Public Sub New()
        ' Empty constructor
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(nRows As Integer, nCols As Integer)
        Stuff = New CodeBlock(nRows - 1, nCols - 1) {}
    End Sub

End Class

Sub Main()
    Dim cb = New Code(1, 2)
    Dim c = New CodeBlock With {.R = 1, .C = 2, .text_tx = "A", .text_bx = "B", .selected = False}
    cb.Stuff(0, 0) = c

    history = New List(Of Code)
    history.Add(cb)

End Sub

You'll want to use a better name than "Stuff" ;)

Thanks, at the moment to avoid too many changes, I'll try first  with: Public history(5) As Object.

@Boy80 Using Object is a small failure, an admission of defeat :( I think Olivier's answer may be closer to what you want.
